# Lag between forecasted and actual values ARDL

Tags: time-series, forecasting, econometrics, stata, ardl

I am computing forecasts with ARDL models of different lag length across both dependent and independent variables.

Regardless of the lag lengths, the actual observations for the dependent variable lag the forecast values consistently by one time period (a quarter in this case).

What could be a possible explanation for this?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

This is quite common in time series forecasting, and there is little you can do about it. If the time series is close to a random walk, the best prediction is close to the last observed value, as the changes in the time series are essentially unpredictable. This way even the best possible forecast ends up lagging behind the actual series by one period.

Comment: What do you think about my answer? If it is helpful and clear, you may accept it by clicking on the tick mark to the left. Otherwise, you may ask for further clarification. A helpful answer can also be upvoted by clicking on the upward-pointing arrow. This is [how Cross Validated works](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tour).